# jQuery remove & add class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this jQuery which allows me to click on a element and it will extended something that is hidden. But you can click on multiple elements and they will all be extended. I only want one to be extended at any one point... Could someone help me out?

```
if( $(window).width() >= 991 ) {
    $('.brands-supply .single').click(function() {
        $id = $(this).attr('href');
        $($id).stop().slideDown('fast');
    }, function() {
        $($id).stop().slideUp('fast');
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="brands-supply hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <h2> Our Consultancy Services </h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <a class="col-md-3 single collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample0" style="background: #464648;" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="http://localhost:8888/eclectic/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cookies.png">
      </a>
      <a class="col-md-3 single collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" style="background: #5e5e5e;" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="http://localhost:8888/eclectic/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Brian.jpg">
      </a>
      <a class="col-md-3 single" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" style="background: #9a9a9a;">
        <img src="http://localhost:8888/eclectic/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Executive_proection_services.jpg">
      </a>
      <a class="col-md-3 single" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3" style="background: #cccccc;">
        <img src="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 collapse" id="collapseExample0" style="height: 0px; background: rgb(70, 70, 72);" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://localhost:8888/eclectic/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/consultancy_icon.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p>Reviews</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>This si a p tag</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 collapse" id="collapseExample1" style="height: 0px; background: rgb(94, 94, 94);" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://localhost:8888/eclectic/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/consultancy_icon.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p>Testing</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>This is a ap tag</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 collapse" id="collapseExample2" style="background: #9a9a9a;">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://localhost:8888/eclectic/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/consultancy_icon.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p>Projects</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>This is a p tag</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 collapse" id="collapseExample3" style="background: #cccccc;">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://localhost:8888/eclectic/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/consultancy_icon.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p>Services</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>This is a Ptag</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Minor quibble: You really should only use $ in a variable name when it's a jQuery object. So for example, $id should just be id. It doesn't affect the *correctness* of the code, but it's just better style.

Answer (score 0):

First click doesn't take two functions as parameters. You should use `slideToggle`.

```
if( $(window).width() >= 991 ) {
    $('.brands-supply .single').click(
        function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('href');
            $('.brands-supply .single').each(
                function () {
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');
                    if (href == id) return;
                    $(href).slideUp('fast');
                }
            );
            $(id).stop().slideToggle('fast');
        }
    );
}
```

So on click select all the elements you attached the click to and iterate over them sliding them up if they are not the current clicked href. Then just use slideToggle on the clicked one and it will slide it up or down based on how its currently displayed.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/xkv31rop/

JS:

```
same as above
```

CSS:

```
div > div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}

#id1 {
    background: red;
}

#id2 {
    background: blue;
}

#id3 {
    background: orange;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="brands-supply">
    <a class="single" href="#id1">id1</a>
    <a class="single" href="#id2">id2</a>
    <a class="single" href="#id3">id3</a>
    <div id="id1"></div>
    <div id="id2"></div>
    <div id="id3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work... Im really stumped to as of why

Comment: @TomTucka Updated answer with a fiddle. Check it out. Did a little guessing at CSS and HTML but the idea is still the same. Also not sure what you tried but my original answer I changed a bit after looking at your code again.